# shell script taking input from java program and try to execute them

Tags: java, linux, shell, client-server, serversocket

Provide some value from UI as client side, This value should be input of shell script which is on server side. So, I have to develop an interface using java whose take value from UI (Client Side) and send for shell script (On Server) as input and try to run shell script on server. Give me direction to do that, because I am new for programming.

Comment: Welcome to programming! Not meant rude, but please have a deep look into [Eric S. Raymond's "How To Ask Questions The Smart Way"](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html). For your current problem: Why does the java GUI have to feed data into a shell script? Cant the problem be solved in pure Java?

Comment: Its expected that arrive here with some code already written and a specific question in mind. Try it out and see how far you get. You can always ask when you get stuck!

Comment: Extend your question with the code for the UI that lets user enter the "value". Tell us the path name of the shell script. Then, we'll show you the rest. -- Being "new for programming" doesn't mean you can ask others to do your work for you.

Comment: Thank you @Markus for your support, If problem can't solved by java then how to do?

Comment: That is what I asked: What does the shell script do what java can't do?

Comment: @laune shell script in home directory of server.

Comment: Anyone tell me how to start to write code and from where to start because I am not getting anything.

Comment: Usually you have a HTML page (displayed by your browser) where you enter some data and a button that sends this to a certain URL. There, the server takes care of executing some shell script using the value as an argument. - Sure, you can do that by a program, independent of a browser. But this isn't something that can be explained here.